# Cherrypy mapping URL to function

Tags: python, http-status-code-404, cherrypy

I'm tying to use Cherrypy for a website, but I have some problem with mapping the url of the page I want to display with function in the python code.

Now I have this code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
localDir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
absDir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), localDir)


import cherrypy
from genshi.template import TemplateLoader
loader = TemplateLoader('../html', auto_reload=True)

class Root(object):

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        tmpl = loader.load('index.html')
        return tmpl.generate().render('html', doctype='html')

    @cherrypy.expose
    def upload(self, datafile):
        #do something
        ...
        return out % (size, datafile.filename, datafile.content_type)

    cherrypy.root.index = index
    cherrypy.root.upload = upload


conf = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'server.config')

cherrypy.quickstart(Root(), '/', config=conf)
```

And the configuration file is this:

```
[/index.html]
tools.staticfile.on = True
tools.staticfile.filename = "/path-to-file/html/index.html"

[/impemails.html]
tools.staticfile.on = True
tools.staticfile.filename = "/path-to-file/html/impemails.html"

[/css/style.css]
tools.staticfile.on = True
tools.staticfile.filename = "/path-to-file/css/style.css"

[/css/index.css]
tools.staticfile.on = True
tools.staticfile.filename = "/path-to-file/css/index.css"

[/css/imp.css]
tools.staticfile.on = True
tools.staticfile.filename = "/path-to-file/css/imp.css"
```

For all the file specified in the configuration file there are no problem, but when I try to access upload with the link http://localhost:8080/upload I get the "404 Not found Message"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 656, in respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 188, in __call__
    self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cperror.py", line 386, in __call__
    raise self
NotFound: (404, "The path '/upload' was not found.")
```

I tried many different ways to solve this problem as shown in the tutorial http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/concepts/dispatching.html but I failed.
I think I'm missing some configurations which are not reported in the tutorial.

Anybody as some ideas?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

My bad, I misunderstood some configurations.
I've solved with this:

```
class Root(object):

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        tmpl = loader.load('index.html')
        return tmpl.generate().render('html', doctype='html')


@cherrypy.expose
def upload(couchdb, maillist, datafile):
    return "upload file"

conf = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'server.config')

root = Root()
root.upload = upload

cherrypy.tree.mount(root, '/', config=conf)
cherrypy.engine.start()
cherrypy.engine.block()
```

Basically I've just moved the function outside the Root class and added the path with `root.upload = upload`

Now it works.